# How do I make an array of ids in one column is Postgresql database?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the permissions table in postgres table

```
CREATE TABLE public.permissions
(
permission_id integer NOT NULL,
crud_signature text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
object_id uuid NOT NULL,
object_type text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
include_subcategories boolean NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT permissions_pkey PRIMARY KEY (permission_id)
)
WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.permissions
OWNER to postgres;
```

and have ROLES table. Each role has multiple permission.

```
CREATE TABLE public.roles
(
role_id integer NOT NULL,
role_name text COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
role_description text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
permissions integer[],
CONSTRAINT roles_pkey PRIMARY KEY (role_id)
)
WITH (
OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

ALTER TABLE public.roles
    OWNER to postgres;

When I try to make a foreign keys column like `permissions` of type `integer[]` Posgres gives me an error that theese fields have incompartables types - `integer` and `integer[]`

What should I do?

Comment: Please include enough sample input and output data in your question to make it clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I try to make a permissions field in ROLES table a foreign key. And it should be an array of permissions keys

Comment: I recommend making a design change, q.v. my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would actually recommend *not* using arrays here.  Instead, use a *junction* table to represent each role-permission relationship, something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE roles_permissions (
    role_id integer NOT NULL,
    permission_id integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT rp_pkey PRIMARY KEY (role_id, permission_id)
);
```

Then modify your current `roles` table by removing the array of permissions.  Your current approach uses unnormalized data, because you are trying to store a set of permissions in an array for each separate role.